# EDT changed to "system" group and Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader() is null

Tags: java, multithreading, classloader

I suddenly got a weird problem in my application, but I am not sure if I can isolate the issue. I couldn't reproduce the bug in a SCCEE, but maybe someone could help me understand what happens by answering the 2 questions below.

**The Context:**

I have, basically this:

```
        ...
        Some treatment
       ->call to json-io to parse a Json String to Java Objects. see below
        ...

        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                myUI.start();//starts my user interface
            }
        });
```

Usually, everything goes fine. But I added to the treatments a call to [Json IO](https://github.com/jdereg/json-io) (a library that parses Json to Java and that I generally use without any trouble).

Now, one of my other library is yelling:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at net.sourceforge.jeuclid.elements.support.ClassLoaderSupport.loadClass(ClassLoaderSupport.java:65)
```

After some researches, I discovered that it is because `Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader()` returns `null`.

I went to the `run()` above and discovered that the only difference between the 2 executions is that the Event Dispatched Thread that used to belong to the group `main` now belongs to `system`:

```
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            System.out.println(Thread.currentThread());
            //returns Thread[AWT-EventQueue-0,6,system] instead of Thread[AWT-EventQueue-0,6,main]
            myUI.start();//starts my user interface
        }
    });
```

In the end, I could solve the problem with

```
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Thread.currentThread().setContextClassLoader(ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader());
                myUI.start();//starts my user interface
            }
        }
    });
```

**The Questions:**

1) What kind of things can make the EDT change group ?

2) What are the consequences of writing `Thread.currentThread().setContextClassLoader(ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader());` ? Is it a good or a bad idea ?

Comment: The bad idea here is to run a long operation (JSON parsing) in the EDT. It is supposed to be used only for quick operations and changes to the UI.

Comment: But... the Json parsing is done before the call to `SwingUtilities.invokeLater`. Sorry if it was unclear. Let me edit.

Comment: It is very odd to have to set the class loader manually. Is there some (buggy) code elsewhere what 'sets the context classloader to null'?

Comment: Not really. The only line related to classLoader is this : `Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().loadClass(className);`. It is used by json-io to instantiate Java object from Json.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your invocation of `SwingUtilities.invokeLater` is the first action that relies on the presence of the EDT, that thread will be created as a byproduct. So the created thread inherits the thread group of the thread which created it, e.g.

```
ThreadGroup tg=new ThreadGroup("foo");
new Thread(tg, ()->
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> System.out.println(Thread.currentThread()))
).start();
```

when performed as first action of an application, will print

```
Thread[AWT-EventQueue-0,6,foo]
```

as you can verify on [Ideone](http://ideone.com/jvQXqI).

But note that the thread group has no impact on the context class loader, it’s rather a symptom of the same cause. The context class loader is just inherited exactly like the thread group when the thread is created, e.g.

```
ClassLoader dummyLoader=new URLClassLoader(new URL[0]);
Thread.currentThread().setContextClassLoader(dummyLoader);
SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() ->
    System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader()==dummyLoader));
```

will print `true`; [(verify on Ideone)](http://ideone.com/u5RZTg).

So apparently, the context loader of the thread which invokes `SwingUtilities.invokeLater`, initiating the EDT creation, is already `null` (and that thread is in the `system` group). Setting the context loader to `ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader()` means setting it to its default, so it has no negative impact unless you encounter an environment where the context loader is intentionally set to a non-default loader, though `null` can not be considered to be such a case. In other words, identifying the place, where it is set to `null` and fixing that, is the better choice.

Comment: Exactly the kind of answer I was looking for. Thanks! I will look into it.